# Combobox problems c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a problem with my combobox, What I'm trying to do is some kind of check. 
So if there is an serialport avalible it should come up in the texbox.

This is my code

```
private void LoadComportName()
{
    if (_comPortComboBox.Contains(SerialPort.GetPortNames()))
    {
        _comPortComboBox.DataSource = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    }
}
```

I think i miss something to make this work. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I will explain it a bit better because its not very clear what i want,
I want that it checks if there are ports available and is so it has to go in the combobox if not the combobox has to say something like "No ports available". But I think I'm doing it to easy

Comment: Your missing your questions detail.. I think you want `combobox.Items.Contains` but no idea if your using wpf/winforms, what serial port relates to, what `GetPortNames` returns..  ["Retrieves a value indicating whether the specified control is a child of the control."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contains.aspx)

Comment: It is a winform app or ASP.NET? What GetPortNames() is supposed to return?

Comment: Also make sure that you are rebinding the combobox.

Comment: Seeing an empty dropdown list is already a *very* strong hint to the user that no ports are available.  Since this probably also prevents your program from being useful at all, you could also simply consider displaying a message box and quit.  If it is not then you could just replace the combobox with a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't invoked `DataBind`:

```
_comPortComboBox.DataBind();
```

You may also be missing the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

```
_comPortComboBox.DisplayMember = "SerialPortName";
_comPortComboBox.ValueMember = "SerialPortValue";
```

These should be set before the `DataBind` method is invoked.

**Edit** (From your comment):

Assuming `GetPortNames` returns a collection.

```
 var availablePorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

 if (availablePorts != null && availablePorts.Any()) {
    // Bind to the available ports. 
 } else {
     _comPortComboBox.Text = "No Ports are available"; 

  }
```

Comment: My problem is not that i cant show the avalible ports. The problem is that when there are no ports avalible i want it to show something like "No porst avalble" but there for i need somekind of check

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept this as an answer as soon as i can